# My c program should be running in several threads using openmp but it isn't

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, openmp

This is a section of my code.It should be using openmp to run this section with as many threads as there is cores but it still runs as one thread. This section of the code is searching through an array and checking if that value is within a certain limit. R and c are ints that represent the rows and columns of the array. The equals method checks if the value in the array is in the limit. If verbose is flagged the value from the array is given the the add_list method that will print it out.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(r,c)

for (r = 0; r < shared_data->sh_rct; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < shared_data->sh_cct; c++)
    {
        equals = (approxEqual(sh_rows[r][c], ref, tol) == 1);

        if(equals)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic

            sh_count++; 

            /*if verbose is true add the match to a list that will be printed out*/
            if(verbose)
            {
                print_list = add_list(print_list, r, c, sh_rows[r][c], omp_get_thread_num());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What types are `c` and `r`?  Not sure if this is still the case, but openmp used to only support ints as loop counts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are only two possibilities for the issue.

1. `shared_data->sh_rct` == 1. In this case, there is nothing to run in parallel.
2. OpenMP runtime was told to limit the number of threads to only one.

The later can be caused by:

- Prior call to `omp_set_num_threads(1)`
- `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable set to 1
- Prior call to `omp_set_dynamic(1)` or `OMP_DYNAMIC=TRUE` in some cases might cause the same behavior.
- The process was allowed to run only on one core. E.g. `taskset -c1 ./your_app`

Comment: shared_data->sh_rct is 1000 and there is no reason that I can see that the number of threads would be limited.This is the only use of openmp in my code

Comment: check you environment and application affinity mask as well

Comment: @Lennygames, which operation system do you use?

Comment: @Lennygames, `taskset -p pid` for the affinity mask and `env` for environment settings.